# Stuck in a git commit loop

Tags: git

When I am trying to commit changes in my git project I keep getting the following message:
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"

Tried all options available on that screen but always get an error
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'

So I reset HEAD and ran 
git rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp

This gives me the error
fatal: pathspec '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp' did not match any files

I navigated to that file and tried to delete it using rm, which does delete it, but it reappears.

Anyone have any idea how to get out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rm`, not `git rm`.  That's a temporary file created by vi, it's not in your git workspace, it's just on your filesystem.

To get it to not reappear, quit vi the correct way.  Use <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to quit and save.  Don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit it.

If the problem with vi doesn't go away, you can change git to use your preferred editor.  Either run

```
git config --global core.editor=<your editor>
```

Or edit your git config file to include this:

```
[core]
    editor = <your editor>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I removed the file using rm and exited vi using :wq, but still get error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.

Comment: Yeah, it had asked me to wait a few minutes before accepting. Thanks again!